# How to make either of the request params mandatory such as one among them can be NULL but not both?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, controller

I have a method in a spring controller

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<RetailerCandidateFormResponse> getRetailerCandidateForm(
   @RequestParam String a, @RequestParam String b, @RequestParam String c) {
    //Method body goes here
}
```

I want `@Requestparam A a` to be mandatory which can be achieved by `@Requestparam(required=true) A a` or by keeping it as it is as, this is a default behavior of `@Requestparam` annotation.

But, what If I want to make either of `@RequestParam String b` or `@RequestParam String c` mandatory i.e. if `@RequestParam String b` is present in request then `@RequestParam String c` need not be present and vice versa but both cannot be `null` a the same time. How can I achieve this at controller level?

Inside method body, I can write this `if-else-if` logic and throw an exception if both the params are `null` but, I don't want to do that.

Comment: You just can't! We can't expect framework to do optional check in 2 different method arguments. Even java doesn't allow it. please proceed with if else with `@RequestParam(required=false)` for b and c`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use @ModelAttribute to get request param from class.
your url will be: `?a=&b=&c=`

Here is soloution:

Use @Validated before controller class.

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<RetailerCandidateFormResponse> getRetailerCandidateForm(
        @Valid @ModelAttribute ReqParam reqParam) {
    //Method body goes here
}
```

request class:

```
public class ReqParam implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@NotEmpty(message = "A can not be null")
private String a;
private String b;
private String c;

@AssertTrue(message = "B or c need to be present")
public boolean isValid() {
    if (b == null) {
        return c != null;
    }

    if (c == null) {
        return b != null;
    }
    return true;
}

//getter seeter
}
```